# how to run a class as a process in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I tried to open several serial ports in python at the same time. I think it makes sense that every port as a class process, then I can group the respective properties and methods within this. Ok, I thought multiprocessing could be fine, but I have struggled to get it to work.

1. Why can't I initialize the serial port in the `init`.
2. When using `super(serialManager, self)` without the `init` the `loop_starter` is executed, but not as a process.
3. `super(serialManager, self).__init__(target=self.loop_starter,args=(serial_port, baudrate, timeout))` isn't executed, why?

how can I properly put all props in a class and process a method inside this class?

regards

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import serial
import time

class serialManager(Process):
    def __init__(self, serial_port, baudrate=57200, timeout=1):
        self.light = False
        self.ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)  #1
        #super(serialManager, self)  #2
        #self.loop_starter(serial_port, baudrate, timeout) #2
        super(serialManager, self).__init__(target=self.loop_starter,args=(serial_port, baudrate, timeout))  #3

    def loop_starter( self, serial_port, baudrate, timeout):  
        print("loop_iterator init")
        ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baudrate=baudrate, timeout=timeout)
        self.loop(ser)

    def loop(self, ser):  
        self.light = not (self.light)
        values = bytearray([2, 82, 49, 4])
        ser.write(values)
        print("loop")
        time.sleep(2)

    #def run(self):
        #print('run')

def main():
    print("main")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    msm = serialManager("COM7")
    print ("inited")
    try:
        msm.start()
        print ("started")

        #while True:
            #main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("caught in main")
    finally:
        msm.join()

        while True:
            main()
            time.sleep (1)
```

ok, I also tried this little script without success. why isnt the run executed?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import time

class P(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(P, self).__init__()
    def run(self):
        print("run")
        #time.sleep(0.5)

def main():
    while True:
        print("main")
        time.sleep(2.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = P()
    p.start()
    p.join()
    main()
```

Comment: your test script executes run for me under python 3.6

Comment: I don't see any reason for you to be sub-classing `Process`. This could all be achieved with just `Process(target=loop_starter,args=(serial_port, baudrate, timeout))`. I noticed you modify, but do not use the variable `light`. Is there something you've not shown, perhaps about interprocess communication?

Comment: @ dunes: ok, where shoud I put Process(target=loop_starter,args=(serial_port, baudrate, timeout)), inside the init? @manu in 3.4.3 there's no printed "run".

Comment: I just tested on 3.4.3 and "run" is printed perfectly.

Comment: but only one time, I thought it would executed all the time.

Comment: why would you expect that? it's not in a loop AT ALL. You started the process ONCE.

Comment: hmmm, how can I start the process forever? I didn't see the point.  the mechanism between class. in the final class I like to have a part that checks the serial connection, when ok then it waits for serial input...  how can I make this 'loop' inside a class.

Comment: oh, I forgotten the while true: in the run statement. now, where can I find infos ybout the communication with the main task?

Comment: what does the p.join() do, when using it the main task isn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your test script executes run() fine. Per the [Process documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process):

> If a subclass overrides the constructor, it must make sure it invokes
>   the base class constructor (Process.**init**()) before doing anything
>   else to the process.

Your `serialManager` class is invoking `super()` at the end instead of the begining of `__init__`